# A Box flashes every few seconds in chrome on right side of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have developed a website for a client, and they keep telling me that when looked at in Chrome on Windows 7 / 8, a white box flashes every 10 seconds or so on the right hand side of the website.

I have Windows 7 on one laptop, windows 8 on another, Latest macbook pro with OSX and chrome and I can't seem to replicate the issue. I tested on browserstack by Adobe with every possible combination and even there I haven't been able to replicate the issue.

The client has tested it on various laptops and most of them show the issue.

Here's the [link](http://www.energyfuturecapital.com/) of the website.
Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4PMEQIWYS3RUpYYk5EcTFPNm8/view?usp=sharing) of the video in which the issue is captured around the **7 second mark**:

Can you see/replicate the issue, if yes, what are your specs/setup, what could be causing it and probable solutions?

Comment: I have looked all over the website but no flashing light. Displayed it in Google Chrome.

Comment: I couldn't replicate it either... Ask your client for the exact specs of his machine. Also, be sure he has the last version of Chrome installed. Another thing that might be important: ask him the resolution of his machine. I've seen the site is built for mobile and you may have some scripts related to window width.

Comment: Thanks @AltayMazlum for having a look;  There is no flashing light but a box which appears for like nanoseconds on the right hand side of the website. I hope you had a look at the video, which makes it easier to spot it.

Comment: @besciualex  Thanks for looking in and thanks for pointing out that it could be resolution dependant.  I will ask the client for the specs and then test the website in those resolutions :)

Comment: @AJ2711 Yes, I've also checked out the video. I've seen the flash in it. But when I checked on my computer, I did not see anything.

Comment: @besciualex  way to go!  So i got the resolution from the client : 1366 x 881 ( viewport ) and i was able to replicate it on my computer !!  Now how to get hold of the problem :P ?

Comment: @AltayMazlum  If you check it in 1366 x 881 resolution/ Viewport , you will be able to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive your problem resides in script.js file.

Try commenting different sections (start with **$("#fullpage").fullpage({..});** ) and reloading until you isolate the problem. Also, I noticed that if you reload the page on 1366 x 881 resolution, and do nothing, nothing happens. But if you move the mouse to the right margin this is what triggers this one-time action.

Once you isolate the problem, you can tell us here if you've solved it or you still need help with it.

Comment: Thanks for all you help. I figured the only things on the website which are repeating with fixed time durations are the animations on the second slide. So i gave an overflow:hidden on the second slide and it solved the issue, No more flashing/flickering on the website :P